# How does this code produce unsigned integer overflow

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following recursive `constexpr` function

```
template<size_t N, size_t O,size_t All>
constexpr int get_indices(const std::array<size_t,N> &products,
                          const std::array<size_t,N>& idx,
                          const std::array<std::array<int,O>,All> &as_all,
                          int i,
                          int it) {

    return it==0 ? as_all[i][idx[static_cast<int>(N)-1]] :
        products[it]*as_all[i][idx[it]] +
        get_indices(products,idx,as_all,i,it-1);
}
```

when called with

```
 constexpr std::array<size_t,2> products = {2,0};
 constexpr std::array<size_t,2> idx = {0,1};
 constexpr std::array<std::array<int,3>,8> as_all = {{{0, 0, 0}, 
      {0, 0, 1}, 
      {0, 1, 0}, 
      {0, 1, 1}, 
      {1, 0, 0}, 
      {1, 0, 1}, 
      {1, 1, 0}, 
      {1, 1, 1}}};

get_indices(products,idx,as_all,4,2); // call it
```

it produces, garbage results. I think it is a problem of unsigned overflow, but I am not quite sure how is it happening. I checked with `gcc` and `clang`.

Comment: Please show us a complete self-contained program whose output exhibits the issue, along with the actual output.

Comment: Why can't people follow simple instructions any more? Always have to ask for an MCVE. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

You have an out-of-bounds access, clang and gcc even tell you that:

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04d63e6d3f06884e)</kbd>

```
main.cpp:28:15: error: constexpr variable 'x' must be initialized by a constant expression

constexpr int x = get_indices(products,idx,as_all,4,2);
              ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.cpp:11:9: note: read of dereferenced one-past-the-end pointer is not allowed in a constant expression
        products[it]*as_all[i][idx[it]] +
        ^
```

The problem is that you try to access `idx[2]` whereas its size is 2, so you can only access `idx[0]` or `idx[1]`